# In Tensorflow's Dataset API how do you map one element into multiple elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In the tensorflow `Dataset` pipeline I'd like to define a custom map function which takes a single input element (data sample) and returns multiple elements (data samples).

The code below is my attempt, along with the desired results.

I could not follow the documentation on `tf.data.Dataset().flat_map()` well enough to understand if it was applicable here or not.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input = [10, 20, 30]

def my_map_func(i):
  return [[i, i+1, i+2]]       # Fyi [[i], [i+1], [i+2]] throws an exception

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input)
ds = ds.map(map_func=lambda input: tf.py_func(
  func=my_map_func, inp=[input], Tout=[tf.int64]
))
element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for _ in range(9):
    print(sess.run(element))
```

Results:

```
(array([10, 11, 12]),)
(array([20, 21, 22]),)
(array([30, 31, 32]),)
```

Desired results:

```
(10)
(11)
(12)
(20)
(21)
(22)
(30)
(31)
(32)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two more steps were required to achieve this. First, the map function needs to return a numpy array, not a list.

Then you can use `flat_map` combined with `Dataset().from_tensor_slices()` to flatten them. The code below now produces the desired result:

Tested in Tensorflow 1.5 (copy/paste runnable example)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input = [10, 20, 30]

def my_map_func(i):
  return np.array([i, i + 1, i + 2])

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input)
ds = ds.map(map_func=lambda input: tf.py_func(
  func=my_map_func, inp=[input], Tout=[tf.int64]
))
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset().from_tensor_slices(x))

element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for _ in range(9):
    print(sess.run(element))
```

---

Here is a method of doing this if you have multiple variables to return, in this example I input a string (such as a filename) and output multiples of both strings and integers. In this case I repeat the string for each of the integers of [10, 20, 30].

Copy/paste runnable example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input = [b'testA', b'testB', b'testC']

def my_map_func(input):
  return np.array([input, input, input]), np.array([10, 20, 30])

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input)
ds = ds.map(map_func=lambda input: tf.py_func(
    func=my_map_func, inp=[input], Tout=[tf.string, tf.int64]))
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda mystr, myint: tf.data.Dataset().zip((
  tf.data.Dataset().from_tensor_slices(mystr),
  tf.data.Dataset().from_tensor_slices(myint))
))

element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for _ in range(9):
    print(sess.run(element))
```

Comment: In tensorflow 1.8, from_tensor_slices and zip are static methods now, so the flat_map line should be:ds = ds.flat_map(lambda mystr, myint: tf.data.Dataset.zip((
  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mystr),
  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(myint))
))"

Comment: Cited from doc. For performance reasons, we encourage you to use TensorFlow operations for preprocessing your data whenever possible.`lambda x : [[x, x+1, x+2]]` should be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

one clean solution using `flat_map` and `from_tensor_slices`

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = [10, 20, 30]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x, x+1, x+2]))
element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(9):
        print(sess.run(element))

# 10
# 11
# 12
# 20
# 21
# 22
# 30
# 31
# 32
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that this can be done for datasets where each element is a dictionary as well. For example, if one element of the input dataset looks like

```
{ 'feat1': [2,4], 'feat2': [3]}
```

And for each element you want to split into to elements based on the elements in feat1, you could write:

```
def split(element):
    dict_of_new_elements = {
        'feat1': [
            element['feat1'][:, 0],
            element['feat1'][:, 1]]
        'feat2': [
            element['feat2'],
            element['feat2']]
    }
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict_of_new_elements)
dataset.flat_map(split)
```

Which would yield

```
[
    {'feat1': 2, 'feat2': 3},
    {'feat1': 4, 'feat2': 3},
]
```