# Tensorflow Dataset - How to build batchs given a generator outputting X inputs for 1 label?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

### Short Version

**Given a generator sampling e.g. `3` inputs and `1` label, how can I define my Tensorflow Dataset pipeline to obtain batches of `K * 3` inputs and `K * 1` labels?**

---

### Longer Version

#### Context

I am using a Triplet network, and want to adapt my current input pipeline to use Tensorflow Dataset.

In my case, a batch consists of `N` (e.g. images) and `N // 3` labels (supposing `N % 3 == 0`), with each label applied to 3 consecutive inputs, e.g.

```python
labels = [compute_label(inputs[3*i], inputs[3*i+1], inputs[3*i+2]) for i in range(N // 3)]
```

with `compute_label(*args)` a simple function, which can be implemented either with Tensorflow operations or basic Python.

To make things a bit more complicated, the input elements must be sampled 3 by 3 (e.g. we want `inputs[3*i]` to be similar to `inputs[3*i+1]` and dissimilar to `inputs[3*i+2]`):

```python
for i in range(N // 3):
    inputs[3*i], inputs[3*i+1], inputs[3*i+2] = sample_triplet(i)
```

#### Question

Reformulating the shorter question to my particular case:

**Given these two functions `sample_triplet()` and `compute_label()`, how can I build my input pipeline using Tensorflow Dataset, to build batches with `N` inputs and `N // 3` labels?**

I tried several combinations of `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` and `tf.data.Dataset.flat_map()` but couldn't find a way to both flatten the batch inputs from `N // 3` triplets to `N` samples, and output only `N // 3` batch labels.

A solution I found was to "cheat" by computing my labels inside `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` and tiling each label 3 times, to be able to use `tf.data.Dataset.flat_map()` over the triplet inputs + labels. As a batch-postprocessing step, I am then "squeezing" the `N` duplicated labels back to `N // 3`.

#### Example with Current Solution

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def sample_triplet():
    # Sampling our elements, here as [class, random_val] elements:
    anchor_class = puller_class = pusher_class = np.random.randint(0, 10)
    while pusher_class == anchor_class:
        # we want the pusher to be of a different class
        pusher_class = np.random.randint(0, 10) 

    anchor = np.array([anchor_class, np.random.randint(0, 5)])
    puller = np.array([puller_class, np.random.randint(0, 5)])
    pusher = np.array([pusher_class, np.random.randint(0, 5)])

    # Stacking the triplets, to then flat_map as a batch:
    triplet_inputs = np.stack((anchor, puller, pusher), axis=0)
    # Returning also the classes to compute the label afterwards:
    triplet_classes = np.stack((anchor_class, puller_class, pusher_class), axis=0)
    return triplet_inputs, triplet_classes

def compute_labels(triplet_classes):
    # Computing the label, e.g. distance between the anchor and pusher classes:
    label = np.abs(triplet_classes[0] - triplet_classes[2])
    return label

def triplet_generator():
    while True:
        triplet = sample_triplet()

        # Current solution: computing the label here too, 
        # stacking it 3 times so that flat_map works,
        # then afterwards removing the duplicates:
        triplet_inputs = triplet[0]
        triplet_label = compute_labels(triplet[1])
        yield triplet_inputs, 
              np.stack((triplet_label, triplet_label, triplet_label), axis=0)

def squeeze_triplet_labels(*batch):
    # Removing the duplicate labels,
    # going from a batch of (N inputs, N labels) to (N inputs, N // 3 labels)
    squeezed_labels = batch[-1][::3]
    new_batch = (*batch[:-1], squeezed_labels)
    return new_batch


batch_size = 30
assert(batch_size % 3 == 0)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
train_dataset = (tf.data.Dataset
                 .from_generator(triplet_generator, (tf.int32, tf.float32), ([3, 2], [3]))
                 .flat_map(lambda *x : tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))
                 .batch(batch_size))

next_training_batch = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
next_proper_training_batch = squeeze_triplet_labels(*next_training_batch)
batch = sess.run(next_proper_training_batch)
print("inputs shape: {} ; label shape: {}".format(batch[0].shape, batch[1].shape))
# >> inputs shape: (30, 2) ; label shape: (10,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution could be to create 2 Dataset objects, one for labels, one for data, then batch the data by groups of 3 and use `tf.data.interleave` to interleave the two datasets back together, producing the results you want.

If that's not easy to do then you could try the following process of mapping one element onto multiple. You would have to create a batch of 3 elements (with 3 labels), then split that in a map function into 3 sets of the data each against one of the labels you received. The recipe for doing that is in the following SO question, though it's a little more involved than the first suggestion:

[In Tensorflow's Dataset API how do you map one element into multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471926/in-tensorflows-dataset-api-how-do-you-map-one-element-into-multiple-elements)

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. The problem here is that each label is computed as a function of the triplet data, so separating their generation in 2 Datasets wouldn't do, I believe.
I tried using `tf.data.Dataset().zip()` along `tf.data.Dataset().from_tensor_slices()`  and `from_tensors()` in `flat_map` (similarly to what you suggested on this other SO thread), but didn't find the proper way to get the batch shape I want (`N` inputs, `N // 3` labels) e.g. Tensorflow would still return `N` labels by filling with those of the next batches...

Comment: Your generator can just produce individual samples in the desired shape, for example `[1, 3, 256, 256, 3]` could be 3 images of shape 256x256x3 (the 3 images that form your triplet), with a batch size of 1 up at the front so you can batch those triplet groups together later. You might have to reshape thing when you pass them through conv layers later, but it can all be achieved usually trivially.

Comment: Right, reorganizing the batches afterwards, outside the `Dataset` API, would be a solution (which is kind of what I resigned myself to do for now, though in a different way c.f. code). I was still hoping to find a solution which could be completely done within `Dataset`, at least out of curiosity.

Comment: The link I referenced there gives you what I believe is the only option in the dataset API, but I don't consider it a particularly elegant solution either.

Comment: Ok, I dug deeper into your suggestions and into my code, and finally found my mistake. I was calling `dataset.batch(N)` after `dataset.flat_map(my_func_to_reorganize_triplets)` (which returns `3*X` inputs and `X` labels). Because of that, `dataset.batch(N)` would not only complete the input elements up to `N`, but also the labels (I was assuming it would keep producing 1 label for 3 inputs). Reversing the two `Dataset` operations solves the problem. Thanks David for the inputs!

Comment: That approach took me many maddening days to wrap my head around too.  :)