# Tensorflow 2.6.0: How do I Map One Element into Multiple Elements

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to make a CNN for classifying medical images. These images are massive (~50k by ~30k). As part of my pipeline, I want to break the images into patches that are 256 by 256.
I want to do this using a `Dataset.map` operator, so I can cache the data later for ease of training.

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471926/in-tensorflows-dataset-api-how-do-you-map-one-element-into-multiple-elements) solving the problem in tensorflow 1, but I have not been able to convert it to tensorflow 2.

I apologize for asking this question, but could I get some help converting the code so I can get it working in tensorflow 2? I am a bit of a newbie so the help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to use `tf.stack` in `tf.data.Dataset.map`, `tf.data.Dataset.unbatch` and the official
[documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)

```py
import tensorflow as tf

some_image_dataset = tf.random.normal(shape=[10, 1024, 768]) 
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_image_dataset)

def some_patches_map_func(image):
    return tf.stack([
        image[10 : 10 + 256, 20 : 20 + 256], 
        image[100 : 100 + 256, 100 : 100 + 256], 
        image[500 : 500 + 256, 200 : 200 + 256],
    ]) 

dataset = dataset.map(some_patches_map_func)
dataset = dataset.unbatch().shuffle(10)
dataset = dataset.batch(2) 
    
iterator = iter(dataset)
        
print(next(iterator).shape) # (2, 256, 256)
print(next(iterator).shape) # (2, 256, 256)
print(next(iterator).shape) # (2, 256, 256)
```

Comment: thanks for your help! If I understand your methods correctly, your function `some_patches_map_func` can be anything so long as it ends with `tf.stack(PATCH_LIST)` it should work? And in your example you arbitrarily took some patches?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. `some_patches_map_func` must return a tensor with shape `(num_patches, patch_height, patch_width)`. `tf.stack` function works for static number of patches. For dynamic number of patches a more advanced approach is needed.